# Durand-Kerner iterative method for multiple roots?

Tags: algorithm, iteration

I am looking at the Durand-Kerner iterative method for Polynomial roots. It has a quadratic convergence rate, However when dealing with polynomial with multiple roots the convergence is only linear. I have been looking around for a modified version of Durand-Kerner that can maintain quadratic convergence rate even for multiple roots?
Any recommendation?

I have got some information about Zeng modification to the Durand-Kerner method that adding some error error corrections but i have been unable to verify where that came from.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_root-finding_algorithms#Finding_all_roots_at_once

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion that I believe should work.

Start with an array of guesses `g`. Then do 3 rounds of iterations like this:

```
p = durand_kerner(poly, g)
q = durand_kerner(poly, p)
g = geometric(poly, g, p, q)
```

The first two iterations are standard. The third works like this for each index `i` in turn:

```
s = p[i] - g[i]
t = q[i] - p[i]
if |t| < |s|:
   a = t / s
   try replacing q[i] in the i'th equation of durand_kerner
      with g[i] + s / (1 - a). Actually do so if it is better
```

The idea is this. Where there are unrepeated roots, the geometric step won't improve. Where there are repeated roots and you are close, the geometric step will be the sum `s + a*s + a^2*s + ...` which should be close to the multiple root.

Comment: Interesting approach. I will try it soon. However is there a reference to an article or similar that analysis this approach?

Comment: @HVE I came up with this based on standard techniques to accelerate infinite sums. I've never seen an attempt to analyze this for root finding.